# Officer package in R : hyperlinks to Word documents

Tags: r, url, ms-word, hyperlink, officer

I would like to add hyperlinks to existing text in a Word document using the officer package ([see cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/index.html)) in R.

Is there a simple way to do this? I do not seem to be able to do it using the function `hyperlink_ftext()`.

Comment: Have you asked the authors of the Office package?